# spring cloud gateway elastic apm

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway, elastic-apm

I'm using spring boot 3 and  spring cloud gateway and I want to trace api using elastic apm but there is problem with tracing api using elastic apm.

Elastic apm can not recognize transactions.

my dependencies :

```
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-api:1.43.0'
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-attach:1.43.0'‍‍‍
```

Elastic apm config:

```
  apm:
    server_url: ${ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:8200}
    secret_token: ${ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN:xxxx}
    environment: ${ELASTIC_APM_ENVIRONMENT:dev}
    log_level: ${ELASTIC_APM_LOG_LEVEL:DEBUG}
    application_packages: ir.zarebin.browser.edge
    transaction_sample_rate: ${ELASTIC_APM_TRANSACTION_SAMPLE_RATE:0.5}
    service_name: edge
    recording: ${ELASTIC_APM_RECORDING:true}
    use_path_as_transaction_name: true
    enable_experimental_instrumentations: ${ELASTIC_APM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_INSTRUMENTATIONS:true}
```

I also attach elastic apm agent to current jvm.

```
ElasticApmAttacher.attach(elasticApm.apm());
```

routeLocator config:

```
 RouteLocator gateway(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, JwtExtractorFilter jwtExtractorFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/auth/login").filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.filter(jwtExtractorFilter.apply())).uri("forward:/login"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/auth/verifyOtp").filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.filter(jwtExtractorFilter.apply())).uri("forward:/verifyOtp"))
                .build
```

[image]

I'm using spring boot 3 and  spring cloud gateway and I want to trace api using elastic apm but there is problem with tracing api using elastic apm.

Elastic apm can not recognize transactions.

my dependencies :

```
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-api:1.43.0'
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-attach:1.43.0'‍‍‍
```

Elastic apm config:

```
  apm:
    server_url: ${ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:8200}
    secret_token: ${ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN:xxxx}
    environment: ${ELASTIC_APM_ENVIRONMENT:dev}
    log_level: ${ELASTIC_APM_LOG_LEVEL:DEBUG}
    application_packages: ir.zarebin.browser.edge
    transaction_sample_rate: ${ELASTIC_APM_TRANSACTION_SAMPLE_RATE:0.5}
    service_name: edge
    recording: ${ELASTIC_APM_RECORDING:true}
    use_path_as_transaction_name: true
    enable_experimental_instrumentations: ${ELASTIC_APM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_INSTRUMENTATIONS:true}
```

I also attach elastic apm agent to current jvm.

```
ElasticApmAttacher.attach(elasticApm.apm());
```

routeLocator config:

```
 RouteLocator gateway(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, JwtExtractorFilter jwtExtractorFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/auth/login").filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.filter(jwtExtractorFilter.apply())).uri("forward:/login"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/auth/verifyOtp").filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.filter(jwtExtractorFilter.apply())).uri("forward:/verifyOtp"))
                .build
```

[image]

Comment: I observe same behaviour with spring 3.1.5 and elastic-arm 1.43.0. Were you able to figure out what is missing?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet